# Can I use Apache-Poi to format Excel spreadsheet as a Table in Streaming Mode

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

A regular spreadsheet (tab) in Excel can be made into a table by selecting the data and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. (This gives each column a header that allows filtering of values).

My spreadsheets are created using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) and the SXSSF streaming interface, I have to use the streaming interface since the spreadsheet can be quite large. Is it possible to programmatically turn each sheet into a table?

I came across **XSSFTable** class but it's not clear how to use it or whether it can be used in streaming mode.

```
package com.jthink.songkong.reports.spreadsheet;

import com.jthink.songkong.db.SongCache;
import com.jthink.songkong.text.SongFieldName;
import com.jthink.songkong.ui.MainWindow;
import com.jthink.songlayer.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Paul on 09/03/2017.
 */
public class SpreadsheetReport
{
    //Max Width we want to use in chars, whatever the data
    public static final int MAX_COL_WIDTH = 100;

    public static final int COL_WIDTH_MULTIPLIER = 256;
    private static final int FLUSH_SIZE = 1000;
    public static final int FONT_MARGIN_OF_ERROR = 5;
    private String reportName;
    private FileOutputStream fos;
    private int rowCounter =0;
    private SXSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private CellStyle headerStyle;
    private CellStyle fieldAddedStyle;
    private CellStyle fieldChangedStyle;
    private CellStyle fieldDeletedStyle;
    private CellStyle fieldUnchangedStyle;
    private List<Worksheet> worksheets;
    private CreationHelper factory;

    public SpreadsheetReport(String reportName) throws IOException
    {
        this.reportName =reportName;
        //Create new File
        fos = new FileOutputStream(reportName);
        workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(FLUSH_SIZE);


        factory = workbook.getCreationHelper();

        worksheets = new ArrayList<Worksheet>();
        worksheets.add(0, new BasicWorksheet(workbook));
        worksheets.add(1, new ReleaseWorksheet(workbook));
        worksheets.add(2, new ClassicalWorksheet(workbook));
        worksheets.add(3, new PeopleWorksheet(workbook));
        worksheets.add(4, new SortWorksheet(workbook));
        worksheets.add(5, new MusicBrainzWorksheet(workbook));
        worksheets.add(6, new MusicBrainzWorkWorksheet(workbook));
        worksheets.add(7, new AcousticBrainzWorksheet(workbook));


        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setBold(true);
        headerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        headerStyle.setFont(font);
        headerStyle.setWrapText(true);

        fieldAddedStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        fieldAddedStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LEMON_CHIFFON.getIndex());
        fieldAddedStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        fieldAddedStyle.setWrapText(true);

        fieldChangedStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        fieldChangedStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_GREEN.getIndex());
        fieldChangedStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        fieldChangedStyle.setWrapText(true);

        fieldDeletedStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        fieldDeletedStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
        fieldDeletedStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        fieldDeletedStyle.setWrapText(true);

        fieldUnchangedStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        fieldUnchangedStyle.setWrapText(true);
    }

    public void writeHeader() throws IOException
    {
        for(Worksheet next:worksheets)
        {
            Row   r = next.getSheet().createRow(rowCounter);
            for(int i=0;i <next.getMapping().size(); i++)
            {
                addHeaderCell(r, i, next.getMapping().get(i));
            }
        }
        rowCounter++;
    }

    private void addHeaderCell(Row r, int spreadsheetIndex, SongFieldNameColumnWidth field)
    {
        Cell cell  = r.createCell(spreadsheetIndex);
        cell.setCellValue(field.getSongFieldName().getName());
        cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
    }

    public void writeDatatoXlsFile(Session session, Song song, List<SongChanges> songChanges) throws IOException
    {
        for(Worksheet next:worksheets)
        {
            Row   r = next.getSheet().createRow(rowCounter);
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell c ;
            c=r.createCell(0);
            c.setCellValue(song.getFilename());

            Map<SongFieldKey, SongChanges> fieldToChanges = new HashMap<SongFieldKey, SongChanges>();
            for(SongChanges nextChange:songChanges)
            {
                fieldToChanges.put(nextChange.getField(), nextChange);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < next.getMapping().size(); i++)
            {
                addFieldValue(session, next , r, i, next.getMapping().get(i), fieldToChanges.get(next.getMapping().get(i).getSongFieldName().getSongFieldKey()), song);
            }
        }
        rowCounter++;
    }

    /**
     * Show the old value as a comment/ttoltip
     * @param r
     * @param c
     * @param sheet
     * @param value
     */
    private void addCellComment(Row r, Cell c, Worksheet sheet, String value)
    {
        String formattedValue    =  value.replace('\u0000', '\n');
        int    rowCount         =  value.split("\\\\u000").length;
        ClientAnchor anchor = factory.createClientAnchor();
        anchor.setCol1(c.getColumnIndex());

        //Wider for filename column
        if(c.getColumnIndex()==0)
        {
            anchor.setCol2(c.getColumnIndex()+5);
        }
        else
        {
            anchor.setCol2(c.getColumnIndex()+2);
        }
        anchor.setRow1(r.getRowNum());
        anchor.setRow2(r.getRowNum()+rowCount);

        // Create the comment and set the text+author
        Drawing drawing = sheet.getDrawing();
        Comment comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
        RichTextString str = factory.createRichTextString(formattedValue);
        comment.setString(str);
        c.setCellComment(comment);

    }
    private void addFieldValue(Session session, Worksheet sheet, Row r, int spreadsheetIndex, SongFieldNameColumnWidth sfncw, SongChanges fieldChanges, Song song)
    {
        SongFieldName   songFieldName = sfncw.getSongFieldName();
        String          value = "";
        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell c ;
        c=r.createCell(spreadsheetIndex);

        //Chnanges have been made to this field
        if(fieldChanges!=null)
        {
            SongChangeType changeType = fieldChanges.getType();
            if(songFieldName==SongFieldName.FILENAME)
            {
                value = fieldChanges.getNewValue();
                c.setCellValue(value);
                c.setCellStyle(fieldChangedStyle);
                //addCellComment(r, c, sheet, song.getFilename());
            }
            else if(songFieldName==SongFieldName.COVER_ART)
            {
                if (changeType == SongChangeType.ADD )
                {
                    CoverImage ci = SongCache.findCoverImageByDataKey(session, fieldChanges.getNewValue());
                    if(ci!=null)
                    {
                        value = ci.getWidth() + " x " + ci.getHeight();
                        c.setCellValue(value);
                        c.setCellStyle(fieldAddedStyle);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MainWindow.logger.severe("Unable to find coverimage for song:"+song.getRecNo()+":"+song.getFilename());
                    }
                    session.flush();
                }
                else if (changeType == SongChangeType.EDIT)
                {
                    CoverImage ci = SongCache.findCoverImageByDataKey(session, fieldChanges.getNewValue());
                    if(ci!=null)
                    {
                        value = ci.getWidth() + " x " + ci.getHeight();
                        c.setCellValue(value);
                        c.setCellStyle(fieldChangedStyle);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MainWindow.logger.severe("Unable to find coverimage for song:"+song.getRecNo()+":"+song.getFilename());
                    }
                    CoverImage ciOrig = SongCache.findCoverImageByDataKey(session, fieldChanges.getOriginalValue());
                    if(ciOrig!=null)
                    {
                        String valueOrig = ciOrig.getWidth() + " x " + ciOrig.getHeight();
                        //addCellComment(r, c, sheet, valueOrig);
                    }
                    session.flush();
                }
                else if (changeType == SongChangeType.NOCHANGE)
                {
                    CoverArt coverart = song.getCoverArts().get(0);
                    value = coverart.getCoverImage().getWidth()+" x" + coverart.getCoverImage().getHeight();
                    c.setCellValue(value);
                    c.setCellStyle(fieldUnchangedStyle);
                }
                else if (changeType == SongChangeType.DELETE)
                {
                    c.setCellStyle(fieldDeletedStyle);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (changeType == SongChangeType.ADD)
                {
                    value = fieldChanges.getNewValue().replace('\u0000', '\n');
                    c.setCellValue(value);
                    c.setCellStyle(fieldAddedStyle);

                }
                else if (changeType == SongChangeType.EDIT)
                {
                    value = fieldChanges.getNewValue().replace('\u0000', '\n');
                    c.setCellValue(value);
                    c.setCellStyle(fieldChangedStyle);
                    //addCellComment(r, c, sheet, fieldChanges.getOriginalValue());
                }
                else if (changeType == SongChangeType.DELETE)
                {
                    c.setCellStyle(fieldDeletedStyle);
                }
                else if (changeType == SongChangeType.NOCHANGE)
                {
                    value = fieldChanges.getOriginalValue().replace('\u0000', '\n');
                    c.setCellValue(value);
                    c.setCellStyle(fieldUnchangedStyle);
                    //addCellComment(r, c, sheet, fieldChanges.getOriginalValue());
                }
            }
        }
        //Field is unchanged
        //Note shoud not be called because we now log unchanged fields as well
        else
        {
            if(songFieldName==SongFieldName.FILENAME)
            {
                value = song.getFilename();
                c.setCellValue(value);
            }
            else if(songFieldName==SongFieldName.COVER_ART)
            {
                if(song.getCoverArts().size()>0)
                {
                    CoverArt coverart = song.getCoverArts().get(0);
                    value = coverart.getCoverImage().getWidth()+" x" + coverart.getCoverImage().getHeight();
                    c.setCellValue(value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                value = song.getFieldValueOrEmptyString(songFieldName.getSongFieldKey()).replace('\u0000', '\n');
                c.setCellStyle(fieldUnchangedStyle);
                c.setCellValue(value);
            }
        }
        sfncw.setColumnWidthFromValue(value);
    }

    public void finish() throws IOException
    {
        for (Worksheet next : worksheets)
        {
            SXSSFSheet sheet = (SXSSFSheet)next.getSheet();

            for (int i = 0; i < next.getMapping().size(); i++)
            {
                int columnWidth = next.getMapping().get(i).getColumnWidthFromValue() + FONT_MARGIN_OF_ERROR;
                columnWidth = columnWidth > MAX_COL_WIDTH ? MAX_COL_WIDTH : columnWidth;
                sheet.setColumnWidth(i, columnWidth * COL_WIDTH_MULTIPLIER);
            }
        }
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
        workbook.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post you code.

Comment: @Aubin okay done so

Comment: @Aubin The problem has been clearly stated, how do format as table, the current code doesnt do that because I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that the xlsx format is simply a series of Xml files compressed into a single zip file. So if I tried creating a table manually within Excel for a worksheet, saving changes, renamed to zip and uncompressing and found it had a created a xl/tables/table1.xml to go with xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml

It consisted of the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<table xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" id="1" name="Table1" displayName="Table1" ref="A1:M13" totalsRowShown="0" headerRowDxfId="0" dataDxfId="1">
    <autoFilter ref="A1:M13"/><tableColumns count="13">
        <tableColumn id="1" name="Filename"/>
        <tableColumn id="2" name="Artist" dataDxfId="12"/>
        <tableColumn id="3" name="Disc No" dataDxfId="11"/>
        <tableColumn id="4" name="Track No" dataDxfId="10"/>
        <tableColumn id="5" name="Single Disc TrackNo" dataDxfId="9"/>
        <tableColumn id="6" name="Title" dataDxfId="8"/>
        <tableColumn id="7" name="Album Artist" dataDxfId="7"/>
        <tableColumn id="8" name="Album" dataDxfId="6"/>
        <tableColumn id="9" name="Artwork"/>
        <tableColumn id="10" name="Year" dataDxfId="5"/>
        <tableColumn id="11" name="Original Release Year" dataDxfId="4"/>
        <tableColumn id="12" name="Genre" dataDxfId="3"/>
        <tableColumn id="13" name="Grouping" dataDxfId="2"/>
        </tableColumns>
        <tableStyleInfo name="TableStyleMedium2" showFirstColumn="0" showLastColumn="0" showRowStripes="1" showColumnStripes="0"/>
</table>
```

Sheet1.xml contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet 
    xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x14ac" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac">
    <dimension ref="A1:M13"/>
    <sheetViews>
        <sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0">
            <selection activeCell="A6" sqref="A6"/>
        </sheetView>
    </sheetViews>
    <sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"/>
        <cols>
            <col min="1" max="1" width="69" customWidth="1"/>
            <col min="2" max="2" width="20" customWidth="1"/>
            <col min="3" max="3" width="12" customWidth="1"/>
            <col min="4" max="4" width="13" customWidth="1"/>
            <col min="5" max="5" width="24" customWidth="1"/>
            <col min="6" max="6" width="32" customWidth="1"/>
            <col min="7" max="7" width="18" customWidth="1"/>
            <col min="8" max="8" width="23" customWidth="1"/>
            <col min="9" max="9" width="13" customWidth="1"/>
            <col min="10" max="10" width="9" customWidth="1"/>
            <col min="11" max="11" width="26" customWidth="1"/>
            <col min="12" max="12" width="36" customWidth="1"/>
            <col min="13" max="13" width="13" customWidth="1"/>
        </cols>
    <sheetData>
        <row r="1" spans="1:13" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
            <c r="A1" s="1" t="s"><v>0</v></c>
            <c r="B1" s="1" t="s"><v>1</v></c>
            <c r="C1" s="1" t="s"><v>2</v></c>
            ................................
            <c r="M13" s="3" t="s"><v>22</v></c>
        </row>
    </sheetData>
    <pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
    <tableParts count="1"><tablePart r:id="rId1"/>
    </tableParts>
```

So table could be created either by parsing the associated sheet or in my case since I am creating the sheet in the first place I have the info I need to create the table xml files , and add them to the zip.

It may be possible to use pois XSSFTable class independently (it has a public constructor) and then render that to Xml, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job you're after:

http://thinktibits.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/Excel-Insert-Format-Table-Apache-POI-Example.html

No point reinventing the wheel when its already there :). Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately since I am using SXSSF there is no equivalent SXSSFTable and hence this cannot be done. I am using SXSSF because sometimes the spreadsheet is large and just using XSSF uses too much memory. Maybe I will have to use XSSF when the spreadsheet is not large and format as table, and when large forgo the table formatting